# Building Xuggler on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, xuggler

I am new to Xuggler, I need to install Xuggler on my machine. I have followed all the steps of http://gregoire.org/2010/08/25/building-the-latest-xuggler-for-windows/. what do i need to do next? 
 Please tell how to check if Xuggler has been installed correctly? and suggest links from where i can learn to start my work on xuggler...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As of Xuggler 5.3 (latest version) which launches next week, you will not NEED to build xuggler for windows unless you need your own version of ffmpeg.

http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/downloads